# What are some software and techniques for extracting proper names from a text?

Tags: parsing, nlp, information-retrieval

I have a large corpus of text-based documents (100,000+) from which I want to extract proper names (e.g. a person's name).

Could anyone recommend techniques and/or software that would be useful in accomplishing this goal. I'm not particularly interested in low-level text parsing, so much as I am in more high-level things such as recognizing and/or ranking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this cannot be done reliably without some form of [Natural Language Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing). A few common issues:

- Names that are also common words: `John Black`
- Multiple languages and various forms of the same word.
- Names that refer to different things. `Lily` could be a name for a person, a place, a cat or just the flower.

NLP can use surrounding grammar constructs to tell some of these cases apart.

That said, a simple (and naive) technique that you could try would be to use the capitalisation of the words. If you see a capital starting letter in the middle of a sentence, it is usually a name of some sort.

You might be able to reasonably assume that any such word refers to the same thing within the same document. Two such words in a sequence are probably a name/surname combination etc.

If capitalisation in the documents cannot be trusted, you might be able to trust that of a proper wordlist, instead, in order to get a list of proper names for the applicable languages.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for Named Entity Recognition? Take a look at the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_entity_recognition) article.

The Stanford NLP group has a decent ready-to-use package [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml), with both GPL and commerical licenses available.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet is to compare each word against a dictionary of proper names.

Comment: This is a good approach, but creating a good dictionary would be difficult, given multiple languages.

Answer (score 0):

What if you made a list of all of the unique words, then removed all of the words that are in a dictionary?

Comment: I'm afraid that won't scale without an automated technique for creating the set of unique words.